# will maximum of convex set function intersect with Boundary?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For a real-valued convex function with the domain is a closed convex set too.

Will the pre-image of the maximum value intersect with the Boundary of the domain?

Comment: Yes. A convex function with a convex domain attains its maximum in the boundary. Firstly you can prove this assuming that the domain is an interval $[a;b]$. Then, if the domain is not 1-dimensional, you can use convexity of the domain to use the same argument of the interval.

Comment: thanks for the comment, would you elaborate a bit here? I kind of get the idea, but sorry I don't have a rigorous background as you. Would be really happy to accept an answer :)

Comment: also from my understanding of your suggestion, the maximum would have to be at the boundary, instead of just intersect right?

Comment: No, take $f=0$ on $(-1,1)$. The preimage of $\{0\}$ is $(-1,1)$ which does not intersect the boundary $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: Would the open interval fits in convex set? Then I should change the terms from convex set to closed convex set

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The open interval is certainly a convex set. If the domain is closed it contains the boundary and so the answer is yes.

Comment: i think i was interested in the closed domain, can you elaborate on the yes part?

Comment: If there is a $\max$ then it either occurs on the boundary or the interior. If it occurs in the interior the function is a constant. If the domain is closed then it contains the boundary in which case the $\max$ occurs on the boundary (it happens everywhere).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is convex (with a convex domain of course) and a $\max$ occurs at an  interior point $x^*$, then $f$ is constant.

Pick any $x \in C \setminus \{x^*\}$, then there is some $y$ such that $x^* \in (x,y)$, that is there is some $t \in (0,1)$ such that $x^* = tx+ (1-t)y$ and
since $f(x^*) \le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y) \le f(x^*)$ we see that $f(x)=f(x^*)$. Hence $f$ is a constant.

If $x^*$ is a $\max$ then either it occurs at the boundary or at the interior.
If it occurs in the interior it is a constant.

If the domain is closed then it will contain the boundary and hence if $f$ is constant then it will attain the $\max$ on the boundary.

Hence if the domain is closed the $\max$ is attained at a boundary point.

Comment: Basically this answer is a better explanation than mine. The idea is simple, however not trivial.

Answer (score 2):

This result is not so simple to prove. I will write you a sketch of the proof, and only in the case when the domain $D$ is compact. In this way it is ensured the existence of a maximum of $f$. Denote by $\partial D$ the boundary of $D$.

Let $f: D \to \Bbb R$ be a convex function, and $D$ is a convex compact set ($D$ is a subset of some $\Bbb R^n$).

Then we need two lemmas:

> Lemma 1: let $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ be a convex function. Then the maximum of $f$ is attained at $x=a$ or at $x=b$.

proof: by contradiction, suppose that the maximum of $f$ is attained in the interior, and that it is stricty larger than $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Try to show that this contradicts convexity.

> Lemma 2: let $x \in D$. Then there exists $y \in \partial D$ such that $f(x) \le f(y)$.

proof: if $x \in \partial D$ ,then pick $y=x$. Otherwise, if $x \notin \partial D$, consider any line passing through $x$. This will intersect $\partial D$ at two points $a,b$. In other words, the interior point $x$ belongs to the segment $[a;b]$ and $a,b$ belong to the boundary of $D$. Then $f$ is convex on $[a;b]$ and you can apply Lemma 1.

Then you can conclude that the maximum of $f$ is achieved at some point on the boundary. Indeed, if the maximum if attained at some $x \in D$, then you can find $y \in \partial D$ with $f(y) \ge f(x)$, so that $y \in \partial D$ is maximum point of $f$.

Comment: It is straightforward to show that if the $\max$ of a convex function occurs in the interior then it is a constant.

Comment: Why do we need Lemma 2? Is Lemma 1 not sufficient?

Comment: @ShivTavker Lemma 1 only talks about functions on an interval. The question is about functions defined on a convex subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x^* $ is local maximizer of $f$, but there is an open ball around $x^*$ contained entirely in $X$, so that $x^*$ is an interior point. Strict convexity implies
$$
f(x') - f(x^*) > \nabla f(x^*)(x'-x^*)
$$
for all $x' \in X$; if $f$ isn't differentiable, substitute a selection from the subgradient into the argument above and below for the gradient, which always exists on the interior for convex functions (Rockafellar's Convex Analysis).

But take
$$
x' = x^* - \varepsilon \dfrac{\nabla f(x^*)}{||\nabla f(x^*)||^2}
$$
where $\varepsilon>0$ is small enough that $x'$ is in the ball around $x^*$. Substituting that in above yields
$$
f(x')-f(x^*) = \varepsilon\dfrac{\nabla f(x^*)'\nabla f(x^*)}{||\nabla f(x^*)||^2} =\varepsilon> 0
$$
so that $f(x') > f(x^*)$ which is a contradiction. So a strictly convex function cannot have a maximizer at an interior point.

One problem is that a function that is convex can still have pretty ugly properties. For example, the function on $X=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^N : ||x|| \le 1\}$ that takes the value zero when $x$ is interior and 1 on the boundary is convex but not strictly convex. On the interior, it is constant, but jumps on the boundary. So the maximizers are the boundary, but that's exactly where the function is discontinuous, and the useful properties of the convexity inequality like interior continuity, a.e. differentiability, and the properties of the subgradient fail. So the weak convexity inequality is not as powerful as you might hope in general.